# Using strcpy() function in C

Tags: c, strcpy

I am presently new to programming and am following the C language which is being taught to us in our College.
I have doubt in the actual functioning of the `strcpy()` function under the header-file `#include<strings.h>`

The general use of this function is given below -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
     char a[] = "google";
     char *b = (char*)malloc((strlen(a) +1)*sizeof(char));
     strcpy(b,a);
     printf("%s, %s\n", a, b); //prints google, google
     free(b);   
}
```

We are given the following format and prototype of the same :

```
char *strcpy( char *to, const char *from)
{
    char *temp = to;
    while (*to++ = *from++);
    return temp;
}
```

I have a couple of doubts about this-

1. What is an extra pointer ( temp ) requirement in the function? Can't we just `return to;` at the end of the function?
2. I convinced myself that the temp variable is used because during each while loop, the pointer `to` is changing itself. That is first `*to` will be assigned `*from` and then `to = to +1`, and `from = from +1`, will take place which will result in changing the address stored in the pointer `to`. But if this is true, then what about the pointer `from`? Will, it also not change at the end of the `strcpy()` function?
3. Where is the function returning the address stored in temp? ( the function should only work if `b = strcpy(b,a);` be mentioned not only `strcpy(b,a);`)

To check the given function I also made my own function "strcpy_me" and used it with the same format and prototype, and it gave the same results.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *strcpy_me( char *to, const char *from)
{
    char *temp = to;
    while (*to++ = *from++);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
     char a[] = "google";
     char *b = (char*)malloc((strlen(a) +1)*sizeof(char));
     strcpy_me(b,a);
     printf("%s, %s\n", a, b); // prints google, google
     free(b);   
}
```

Please help me clarify my doubt.

Comment: 1) `to` changed value within the function; you can return the changed value... but the calling function has no use for it. 2) Correct. the **local** pointer `from` will change inside the function: no other variable outside changes. 3) Returning `temp` allows you to do `strcpy(foo, strcpy(bar, "quux"));` 4) Is there a question?

Comment: 1. The reason given in second point is correct. 2. What about the `from` pointer? It does change but why is that a problem? 3. The return value is stored wherever you choose to store it to. It's not clear what you are asking there.

Comment: @pmg `from` is not only a local pointer. It's the address of the string a. I believe that as we call this function by reference ( and not by value ), at the end our char *a would be pointing to NULL and not the first char of "google". So while printing `a` in the `main` function, should have given nothing, instead of printing 'google' back. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, and in C returning from `malloc()` doesn't need a cast

Comment: Aside: cast not needed.  Size to the referenced object. `char *b = (char*)malloc((strlen(a) +1)*sizeof(char));` --> `char *b = malloc(sizeof *b * (strlen(a) +1));`

Comment: @granthium: C has no concept of "call by reference". `from` is a local variable (a local pointer). Changes to `from` (to the pointer) inside the function do not change any variable outside the function... changes to `*from` (to whatever `from` currently points to) may change outside objects.

Answer (score 2):

1. see 2
2. It's a requirement from the implementation of strcpy to return a pointer to the beginning of the destination string. So if you want to implement your function in the same way as `strcpy`, you'll have to save a copy of the original pointer passed as parameter, in case you intend to change that parameter inside the function. This isn't a particularly useful or rational feature, but strcpy has been like that since the dawn of time.
3. Not sure what you mean; here obviously: `return temp;`
4. `return to;` is wrong. You have to realize that the function returns a value whether that value is used by the caller or not. Strict compilers might warn "value from function isn't used" in which case you'd have to write `(void) strcpy(a,b);` to silence it. Since your example doesn't use the returned value, it doesn't matter that it is wrong.

Comment: 2. ok I get your point    3. I meant that the function is just returning the address of the destination string, but it's not stored anywhere. I believe that the char * which is returned should be stored as `b = strcpy(b, a);` rather than just commanding `strcpy(b, a);`  4.Yeah I am sorry, I corrected that. I had used that to see what would happen in this case `return to;`.

Comment: @granthium The destination string is `b` itself. Doing `b = b` isn't necessary. You just need to execute `strcpy(b, a)`.

Comment: @granthium You can ignore the return value of `strcpy` since you know what it will return anyway. I believe the reason for it is to allow chaining of function calls like `strcat(strcpy(dest, "foo"), "bar")` which was probably considered reasonable programming style back in the 1970s.

Answer (score -1):

1. What you think in no. 2 is correct.
2. `from` does get changed but we don't need the previous value of `from`. `to` was stored in `temp` as `to`'s original value should be returned, so we need it but no need for `from`.
3. No, you don't need to do that. You can ignore return values in C(in most cases without warnings as well). No returning works as doing `*to = *from` changes the parameter's memory as well, in this case, b. So, `*to = *from` changes the array `b` directly. It is because `to` and `b` store the same memory.

Note: In your while loop, it's `*to++ = *from++`. It uses post addition, which for simplification, I didn't include here but all it does is increment both `to` and `from` after the operation.

4. As I said in 3, you don't need the return value. In fact, because original `to` and `temp` point to the same memory as `b`, the function returns `b` itself. doing, `b = strcpy_me(b, a)` is the same as:

   ```
    strcpy(b, a);
    b = b; //b's value stays the same
   ```

And yes, `return temp;` is absolutely garbage in my opinion. It only causes confusion.